# Не компилируются импортируемые sass

Tags: css, sass

Стоит Live Sass Compiler, имеется основной style.sass и импортируемые в него файлы (_media.sass). Ранее мог сохранять изменения в импортируемых и основной так же сохранялся, но теперь же приходится после сохранения того же _media открыть style.sass и сохранить его, тогда изменения применяются.

Comment: `_media.scss` является файлом, который не должен быть скомпилируем, а лишь заброшен в главный компилируемый файл, в вашем случае `style.scss`, возможно это и вызывает проблему.

Comment: Всё верно, но почему раньше не было такой проблемы? Сохраняя _media.scss сохранялся и главный, а сейчас приходится переключаться между ними

Comment: Не уверен насчёт ответа, но возможно что-то с конфигурацией вашего компилятора.